# How to parse xs:date with NodaTime?

Tags: c#, xsd, timezone-offset, nodatime

I have to process XML documents sent by various external systems that also contain some dates. `xs:date` allows adding a "time zone", i.e. an offset, to a date. E.g. `"2017-06-02+03:00"` is a valid value. Also, offsets are not used consistently in a single XML document. Some dates have an offset, most do not.

`LocalDatePattern.IsoPattern` does not handle values with an offset and my attempts at a custom pattern were also fruitless.

What would be the best way to parse these values into a `LocalDate`?

I debated to 2 possible options:

1. Simply strip the offset part from the textual value and continue using `LocalDatePattern.IsoPattern`.
2. Use `OffsetDateTimePattern` with a custom pattern that does not contain the time part and then construct the `LocalDate` manually from the parsed value.

I ended up going with option 1, because I do not need the offset for any conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work well for your use case:

```
public static bool TryParseXsDate(string xsDate, out LocalDate localDate)
{
    // First try directly, since xsDate's offset is optional.
    var result1 = LocalDatePattern.Iso.Parse(xsDate);
    if (result1.Success)
    {
        localDate = result1.Value;
        return true;
    }

    // Now try with an offset
    var result2 = OffsetDatePattern.Parse(xsDate);
    if (result2.Success)
    {
        localDate = result2.Value.Date;
        return true;
    }

    // Failed parsing
    localDate = default(LocalDate);
    return false;
}
```

This will ignore the offset in all cases.

If you actually *need* the offset, keep in mind that `xs:Date` defines it as the offset for the first moment of the date.  Therefore, once applied to a time zone, midnight *could* appear twice on that day, or the day might start at 1:00 AM.  You would need a custom `ZoneLocalMappingResolver` function to deal with that properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would parse the value as `OffsetDateTimePattern` as that most closely represents the information you actually have in the text. My experience is that it's best to parse in a form that retains all the information you need, then use the Noda Time APIs to change to a format that you actually *want*... rather than do the transformation on the string and then parse.

Benefits of that:

- It validates all the text, not just the text you're interested in. The value "2017-06-09-badger-badger" clearly suggests there's something very wrong, but if you're using a substring approach you'd miss that.
- It's more robust - you're less likely to end up with magic numbers in your code, and it's much easier to handle things like variable-width formats (not a problem in this specific case, of course)
- It makes it easier to change your mind about what you want, because the decision remains entirely in the "date and time" domain, not the "text parsing" domain.

The only exception I normally make to this is if the string is unparseable at the moment - e.g. it includes some unsupported aspect like ordinals ("June 3rd 2017").

We could consider adding this as a text format for `LocalDate` - I don't anticipate creating an `OffsetDate` type, unless there's significant demand.

Comment: In my opinion, xs:date with an offset makes no sense. Having a built-in pattern for LocalDate would make life easier for those unfortunate enough to receive such values, but I wouldn't want to encourage even more people to use this format. Also what would be the output of this hypothetical LocalDatePattern.XsDate.Format(LocalDate)?

Comment: @Lauri: You'd probably be able to configure the offset to use. But I agree it's weird.